# jquery change data-placement based on value

Tags: jquery

Is there any way in jquery, how to scan all elements for specific data-placement value (e.g. "right") and replace it to "top" for all mobile screens (e.g.smaller than 768px)?

I mean to scan all html elements (not just these based on css class, because it can be textarea, input, etc).

I know, that I can set value e.g. `$(".dog").attr("data-placement", "top");`but no idea how to scan all html elements. Many thanks.

Comment: Use an attribute selector: `$("[data-placement=right]").attr("data-placement", "top");`

Comment: perfect. Thank you!